cdk: use aws_iam.ArnPrincipal to grant repository
I want to enable (cross-account) access to a repository.
But my statement seems not to have any effect.
repository.grant_pull(aws_iam.ArnPrincipal('arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/technical-role'))

I even don't see any changes in the resulting template after synth, no matter if I add the line or comment it out.
Do I have missed some point?

Is the repository being created within the same CDK stack/app?

yes it is, and is working fine. other service-roles can be granted without a problem.

Try importing the role with Role.from_role_arn and granting access to that

still don't know, why the obvious approach didn't work, but found a solution basing on this, that and this
in the cdk with the repo (the account 999999999 where the source-code resides):
def get_repository(self, kms_key, service_role):
    repository = aws_codecommit.Repository(
        self,
        "TechMainCdkAppRepository",
        repository_name="tech_main_cdk_app",
        description="Contains the Code to form the main stages",
        kms_key=kms_key,
    )
    proxy_role = self.get_stage_proxy_role()
    repository.grant_pull(proxy_role)
    kms_key.grant_encrypt_decrypt(proxy_role)
    repository.grant_pull(service_role)
    return repository


def get_stage_proxy_role(self):
    role = aws_iam.Role(
        self,
        "StageAccountProxyRoleCodecommit",
        assumed_by=aws_iam.ArnPrincipal(
            "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/codebuild-cdk_app-build_and_deploy_stage-run"
        ),
        role_name="codecommit-stage_account_proxy_role",
    )
    return role

Take care: when using a custom kms-key the grant kms_key.grant_encrypt_decrypt(proxy_role) is crucial, as without that you always get a 403-error and (like me) will maybe search for the error in the wrong place.
in the cdk with the "guest" (the account 123456789, you want to do your git pull/clone):
service_role = aws_iam.Role(
    self,
    "MainStageDeployRole",
    assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("codebuild.amazonaws.com"),
    role_name="codebuild-cdk_app-build_and_deploy_stage-run",
)

service_role.add_to_policy(
    aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
        resources=[
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-*",
            "arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/codecommit-stage_account_proxy_role",
        ],
    )
)

now start a CodeBuild-job with the service-role and inside your buildspec.yaml do the magic:
      - aws configure --profile proxyrole set role_arn arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/codecommit-stage_account_proxy_role
      - aws configure --profile proxyrole set credential_source EcsContainer
      - aws configure --profile proxyrole set account 999999999
      - git clone codecommit://proxyrole@tech_main_cdk_app


So granting to the imported role with Role.from_role_arn didn't work?

sorry, forgot to answer: no, it didn't work. I think creating a explicit proxy-role is the only way to achieve the cross-account-privilege.
